# How to use fitdist function (negative binomial)?

Tags: r, dplyr, distribution, fitdistrplus

I have the following data set

```
aa <- data.frame("set_up" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), set = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3), mass = c(45,12,34,7,1,433,56,12,54,6,7,8))
```

I want to find the parameter k of the negative binomial function grouped by set and set_up.

The `fitdist(data = aa$mass, distr = "nbinom", method = "mle")$estimate[[1]]` gives the value of the k parameter. I want to estimate the k for each group of set_up and set.

Here is the dplyr code for it

```
library(fitdistrplus)
aak <- aa %>% 
  group_by(set_up, set)%>% 
  summarise(ktotalinf = fitdist(data = aa$mass, distr = "nbinom", method = "mle")$estimate[[1]])%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

I get an output, but it is the same value repeated for each row.
 This value of the estimate[[1]] is the same as if all the mass data were pooled (and not grouped). Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: You need `data = mass` instead of `data = aa$mass` within summarise

Answer (score 1):

You got the answer, but not the reasoning behind it. The magrittr/dplyr mechanism is to create a local environment for the application of each successive function along the chain of `%>%` passages.

When you gave the `fitdistrplus::fitdist` function the data argument of `aa$mass`, you actually went outside of the local environment where the values had been separately grouped by your `"set"` variable. The is no `aa`-named entity inside the local environment. There *is* an entity named `.` (a period), which gets passed along from function to function, getting altered in some manner at each step. Instead of `apply`-ing the function to each group, `fitdist` always got the same argument, which was the entire dataframe. When you change the data argument to `mass`, the R interpreter first looks inside the local environment and does find a named entity within each group.